# Filtering multiple types of content in graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using GatsbyJS and this is my first adventure with react and graphql. I am wanting to mix a single page's content to contain both "blog-post" type content, and "repo-post" type content, but I don't know how to add that to the query to filter for it.

Additionally; I know what frontmatter is (re: markdown), but I don't know what templateKey, and "eq" are in this context. I don't know enough about what I am looking at to know what it's called to start searching for an explanation.

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] },
      filter: { frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "blog-post" } }}
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 400)
          id
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            templateKey
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`eq` here means equals and `templateKey` is just another key in your markdown frontmatter. You given filter is essentially saying "if the `templateKey`'s value in `frontmatter` equals blog-post".

You can change the filter 
from

```
filter: { frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "blog-post" } }}
```

to

```
filter: { frontmatter: { templateKey: { in: ["blog-post", "repo-post"] } }}
```

You should check out the [docs on graphql](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/). It also has a great tool called GraphiQL to play around with queries.

Comment: got it, so drawing an analogue to sql, "frontmatter" here is similar to the "table", "templatekey" is the column, and eq/in (others im sure) are the comparison operation, and then either the value, or an array. I know they aren't the same, but I'm trying to adapt a mental model to make this make sense.